The volume of a tetrahedron $ABCD$ is $\frac{1}{6}$. Determine $CD$ knowing that $\angle ACB=45$ and that $AD+BC+\frac{AC \sqrt{2}}{2}=3$.
the question
The volume of a tetrahedron $ABCD$ is $\frac{1}{6}$.  Determine $CD$ knowing that $\angle ACB=45°$ and that $AD+BC+\frac{AC \sqrt{2}}{2}=3$.
my drawing

my idea
From the equality we can say that
$AC \sqrt{2}=6-2AD-2BC$
From the thorem of the cosine applied in the triangle ABC $AB^2=AC^2+BC^2-AC×BC×\sqrt{2}$
Also we can say that the area $A(ABC)=\frac{AC×BC×\sqrt{2}}{4}$ and the volume of the tetrahedron is $V(ABCD)=\frac{1}{6}=\frac{AD×BC×dis(AD,BC)×\sin(AD,BC)}{6}=\frac{AC ×BC ×\sqrt{2}×dis(D, (ABC) )}{12}$
Im pretty sure we need some auxiliar constructions but dont know which one. Hope one fo you can help me! Thank you!

Let's define: $x=BC$, $y=AC/\sqrt2$, $z=AD$. We obtain then, from the given relations:
$$
x+y+z=3
$$
and
$$
xyh=1,
$$
where $h$ is the distance of $D$ from plane $ABC$. The tetrahedron can exist only if $z\ge h$, that is if:
$$
xyz\ge1.
$$
But from AM-GM inequality we have:
$$
1={x+y+z\over3}\ge\root3\of{xyz}\ge1,
$$
hence arithmetic and geometric mean are the same, implying
$$
x=y=z=1.
$$
We also get $z=h=1$, that is $AD$ is perpendicular to plane $ABC$. From that it is easy to find $CD=\sqrt3$.

Thank you so much for your answer! I don't understand what do you mean with plane z tangent to the surface z. Can you explain it? (maybe not using these terms)

I mean: function $f(x,y)=3-x-y-{1\over xy}$ has its maximum at $x=y=1$ and $f(1,1)=0$.

Ohh....is tehre any way to solve it without functions or coordinate geometry? I don't know these two lessons yet...Thanks again!

Maybe using AM-GM inequality, but I'm not sure.

I am thinking about processing the inequality a bit and arriving to showing $3xy-x^2y-xy^2-1\geq 0$ only if x=y=1, but I don't know how to demonstrate it

I edited my answer and got the same result using AM-GM inequality.
